# How can I show size of the filesystem cache that has to be synced?

Tags: linux, caching, filesystems

With the command `sync` I can synchronize the filesystem cache to the physical disks. But how can I see how much data still has to be synced?

This could be helpful to see how much time it will take until I can remove a USB stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/meminfo` can tell you this information:

```sh
cat /proc/meminfo | grep -e Dirty -e Writeback
```

According to [kernel documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.rst#meminfo),

```
Dirty
              Memory which is waiting to get written back to the disk
Writeback
              Memory which is actively being written back to the disk
```

I don't think there is a way to determine how much Dirty or Writeback memory is specific to a device though.